# Lost Update Scenario Concurrency

Tags: concurrency, scheduled-tasks

```
Time        T1               T2 

t1          READ(A)     
t2          A = A - 50       
t3                           READ (A)          
t4                           A = A - 100
t5                           WRITE (A)
t6                           READ (B)
t7          WRITE(A)
t8          READ (B)
t9          B = B + 50
t10         WRITE (B)
t11                          B = B + 10
t12                          WRITE (B)
```

Can someone help me understand this schedule above and tell me if my interpretation is correct:

1) Assuming A = 300 first T1 will read A and subtract 50 so A = 250.
2) Then T2 (at time = `t3`) will Read(A) but it will read 300 (original value of A not updated value from time  = `t1`) since `t1` never said `WRITE(A)` in its execution after `A = A - 50` correct?
3) Then in T2 (at time  = `t4`) `A = A - 100` so A is 200 and T2 will write that value to A. Then it will read B.
4) Now my question is when `WRITE (A)` on `t7` will it write the value of A from step 3 (200) or the value of A from step 1 which is 250?

Comment: Why did you tag this with sql? This doesn't look like SQL at all to me.

Comment: I thought this was related to SQL but ok I will remove the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I share your interpretation

If T1 modifies A locally, then yes, it will write 250 from within  T1.

But this sounds really architecture dependent. If A is shared by both thread, then T1 will write 200, because A will have been re-read, then decreased with 100.

To have a more accurate answer, I suggest you define what `READ()`, `A = A + N` and `WRITE()` really does. It seems to involve memory and files, but how to guess what you have in mind?

Probably another easy way to know, is to implement this.

Hope it helps